# Nsuserdefaults highscore saving

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

```
var score = 0
var highscore = 0
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

@IBOutlet weak var scoreResult: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var highScoreResult: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let hscore = defaults.valueForKey("highscore") {
        highScoreResult.text = String(hscore)
    }
}

@IBAction func tapPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    score++
    scoreResult.text = String(score)
   if score > highscore {
    highscore = score
        highScoreResult.text = String(highscore)
        defaults.setValue(highscore, forKey: "highscore")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

When i press "tapPressed" button, score++ , then it saves as highscore, the problem is that when i restart app and i have highscore saved. When i press "tapPressed" highscore starts from zero again.

Comment: You don't set `highscore` when reading the user defaults in viewDidLoad, so it will be zero each time the view controller is loaded.

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me, what should i add in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change viewDidLoad to:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let hscore = defaults.valueForKey("highscore") {
        highscore = hscore
        highScoreResult.text = String(hscore)
    }
}
```

That should load the highscore from the defaults once you're app launches.

Comment: Its not at all a good approach to use valueForKey for setting or getting values from user defaults, rather use the actual type ones like stringForKey,  boolForKey, intForKey etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewDidLoad` you need to change your statement to this:

```
if let hscore = defaults.valueForKey("highscore") {
    highscore = hscore
    highScoreResult.text = String(hscore)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are describing the reason for the error. In addition I'd like to describe also to use `NSUserDefaults` properly.

The recommended way is to register the key/value pairs to have reliable default values in case the preference file will be deleted or the app launches the first time.

In AppDelegate (`applicationDidFinishLaunching` or earlier) register `highscore` with a value of 0.

```
let defaultValues = ["highscore" : 0]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

Then in `viewDidLoad` just write

```
let highscore = defaults.integerForKey("highscore") 
highScoreResult.text = String(highscore)
```

There is no optional binding needed because the value in user defaults is always a  non optional.

To save `highscore` back to disk use the dedicated method `setInteger:forKey:`

```
defaults.setInteger(highscore, forKey: "highscore")
```

`valueForKey:` is a KVC method with a special meaning and should not be used with `NSUserDefaults`.